Avoiding Information Leakage in Backtesting with CPCV-Tuned Hyperparameters
I'm using Combinatorial Purged Cross-Validation to tune hyperparameters for a binary classification model applied in a month-end trading strategy. I have 6 months of data and used CPCV with 15 splits to determine the optimal hyperparameters. After tuning, I trained the final model on the entire dataset using these hyperparameters.
My concern is regarding backtesting: If I use these CPCV-tuned hyperparameters on the same 15 splits during backtesting, am I introducing information leakage?
I feel like I might be misinterpreting CPCV. Could someone clarify if this approach is correct or suggest how to properly conduct backtesting in this context?

